# change he background color of listview using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

I try to change the background color of `listview` in html using `color` variable in html but its no working but when am assign  simple `background-color:red;` then its working, but I want to change the color using `color` variable.

```
   <ul>

   <script>

var d = new Date();
var d = new Date();

var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

var color="red";
var day=d.getDay();

  for(var i=0;i<7;i++)
  {

  if(day==7)
 day=0;
 document.write("<li style='background-color:'"+color+"';'>");   

  document.write(weekday[day]); document.write("</li>");
 day++;

 }  
 </script>
 </ul>

   }        
   </script>

    </ul>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to quote "red"

Change

```
document.write("<li style='background-color:'"+color+"';'>");   
//Single quote removed                      ^         ^
```

to

```
document.write("<li style='background-color:"+color+";'>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap color in quotes.

```
document.write("<li style='background-color:" + color + ";'>");   
// remove single quote here                 ^           ^
```

Here is the working link [Demo](http://jsbin.com/pukat/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra one single quote near the color variable

```
document.write("<li style='background-color:"+color+";'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.write('<li style="background-color:'+color+';">');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect.Change this line-

```
document.write("<li style='background-color:"+color+";'>");
```

This is tested and working.